# Rails Display Commenter Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm totally new to rails.  I did the blog tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

I have the application up and running, but here's what I want to do: I want to be able to display the the name of the person currently logged in.  So I want to take out this: <%= f.text_field :commenter %> and replace it with the name of the current person logged in.

I've tried different approaches and get many nilClass errors and undefined variable messages.

I basically have searched everything on stack overflow and nothing helps get the name displayed.  I don't even know what else to change in models or controllers, I've done so much searching I feel like I'm overwhelmed because nothing is working.

In the view posts/show.html.erb there is a field for a commenter to enter his/her name.  Here's the code that I want to change:

**posts/show.html.erb**

```
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :body %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

**PostsController.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**Comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  attr_accessible :body, :commenter
end
```

Comment: This question is too long, please consider revising the questions according to the SSCCE document.

Comment: Well how do you have your login / sessions working?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to track user sessions. I'd start with section on sessions in the Action Controller guide:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

Comment: @Aaron: From his question, he made it sound as if he is already tracking the user sessions.

Comment: Do you have the usual `current_user` method defined? Then you'd `<%= current_user.name %>` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.  I do have my current login working, but am unfamiliar with the use of sessions.  But I can log in and create different accounts etc.  I do not think I have a current_user method defined.  I have a controller named user_controller.rb.  Where would I go to define (model or controller of comment or user to create the current_user method?)  Again, I'm really new to this, but am trying to expand my knowledge and really want to display the name of the person that is logged in when they comment.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: For the record, you can see the exact code used at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html as you scroll through you will see how it's set up.  If you look the first section of code above, I think I need to change <%= f.text_field :commenter %> to something like <%= current_user.name %>, but don't know where I need to define other methods to make it work.

Comment: I'm working on a project with some others...here is the link to the github account to pull the entire project (should someone really want to do that). https://github.com/earasoft/AdvWebDev2013Project.git

Comment: Please look at my previous comment in regards to user sessions. The link to the Rails Guides explains how to create the current_user method. Once you've done that, you can use `<%= current_user.name %>`, just as mu has suggested.

Comment: Aaron, thank you!!  I'll let you know how it works out.

Comment: Aaron, quick question...does all the code for the sessions go in the comments controller, user controller or other?  I just want to make sure I put the code in the correct place, again, thanks for your help.